# Autohotkey: Remap Win key - when pressed alone

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Because of an insane laptop keyboard layout and the inability to map Fn-combinations I want to do a few remappings.  I would like to use the LWin key as modifier (such as LWin+Right ==> End, etc.).  It works just fine.

However, I want to stop LWin, when pressed and released alone, to bring up the Windows menu (b/c I sometimes press the modifier but then decide not to complete the action) **and** I still want to be able to access the Windows menu fairly easily,  say via LAlt+LWin.  (Obviously LWin must act as a proper modifier otherwise.)

So I tried:

```
#LAlt::Send {LWin}
```

which kinda works but ugly (needs LWin kept pressed while Alt is pressed and released). It would be more natural the other way round, i.e.

```
!LWin::Send {LWin}
```

but it doesn't work (not even with a `$` or `~` prefix).

Worst of all I have had no success disabling the LWin key **alone** in such a way that it still works as a modifier:

```
LWin::Return
```

kills it completely.

I'm new to autohotkey (have had luck with keyboards, I guess ;)); what's a good way to solve these?

---

Update: here is my hotkey file in full so far:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#InstallKeybdHook

; Win + arrows
*#Right::Send {End}
*#Left::Send {Home}
*#Down::Send {PgDn}
*#Up::Send {PgUp}

; Sane CapsLock: make it Shift, Shift+CapsLock as CapsLock
CapsLock::Shift
+CapsLock::CapsLock

; Alt-Win to Win (so that Win menu is accessible still)
;   and disable Win alone (so that it won't pop up with navigation)
;??????????????
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
LWin up::return
<!Lwin::
    send ^{Esc}
return
<#right::
    send {end}
return
```

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> instead of <kbd>LWin</kbd> here does the trick.

Comment: Thanks!  I tried and it has indeed properly handles LWin alone.  However, it seems to have killed my other combos (such as LWin+Right ==> End: *#Right::Send {End}).  Any chance to revive them?

Comment: I copied these 4 lines at the end of my script (see above in updated question) and it seems not to work.  LAlt+LWin does bring up the menu but LWin also brings up the menu alone and LWin+Arrows work as per Windows 10 defaults.

Comment: @fastcatch actually initial code worked, the problem was you need to use `<#` (Lwin) with other hotkey to make it work. Added example.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand but it does work like this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, especially for who want to remap depending on long-press or short-press.

---

For me, I only want to prevent the `start menu` when I had pressed down the win key and finally give up the next combination key ……

```
~LWin::__Disable_LWin()
            __Disable_LWin() {
                Send, {Blind}{vkFF}
                if (TickCount_When_LWinPressedDown = 0) {
                    TickCount_When_LWinPressedDown := A_TickCount
                }
            }
LWin Up::__Enable_LWin_ForShortPress()
            __Enable_LWin_ForShortPress() {
                if (A_PriorKey == "LWin") {
                    if (A_TickCount - TickCount_When_LWinPressedDown < 800) {
                        Send, {Blind}{LWin}
                    }
                }
                TickCount_When_LWinPressedDown := 0
            }
```