# Remap only Windows key, keeping windows key combinations

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I wish to remap only Left Windows key when pressed alone and keep every Left Windows key combination such as LWin+Left/Right etc

So far no solution I've tried worked very good: Sometimes the script does not intercept windows key and mostly doing something in between the default windows behavior and the autohotkey script behavior.

This is the script with the best results so far:

```
$LWin::
    KeyWait, LWin, T0.3
    If !ErrorLevel {
        Send, +!{space}
    }
    Else {
        Send, {LWin Down} 
    }   
    KeyWait, LWin
Send, {LWin Up}
Return
```

Things I've tried:

- [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067999/autohotkey-remap-win-key-when-pressed-alone)
- [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AutoHotkey/comments/39fpj7/windows_key_press_remapping/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
LWin up::
If (A_PriorKey = "LWin") ; LWin was pressed alone
    Send, +!{space}
return

; In this case its necessary to define a custom combination by using "&" or "<#" 
; to avoid that LWin loses its original function as a modifier key:

<#d:: Send #d  ; <# means LWin
```

Comment: This is amazing, I can't thank you enough! Been testing it for half a day now and it works like a charm!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: Would it be also possible to ignore "LWin" key if combined with left mouse click?

Comment: Try adding: `<#LButton::return ; do nothing`.

Answer (score 2):

**Run the AHK elevated.**

You say

> Sometimes the script does not intercept windows key and mostly doing something in between the default windows behavior and the autohotkey script behavior.

If you encounter non-deterministic behavior of AutoHotKey, run it elevated, i.e. **As Administrator**.

I faced this problem often in my scripts until I have found that AHK does not reliably catch system-related shortcuts or keys (they sometimes work and sometimes don't) unless it is launched as administrator. The last system where this was not required was Windows XP. Troubles started with Windows 7.

- **So instead of creation of spohisticated workaround scripts, return to straightforward ones which did not run reliably before, and try them with elevated AHK.**

Tip: If you want the AHK to be run elevated on every login of your user, run it using scheduled task (created via Task Scheduler) and give the task administrator privileges.